# Getting all results in Join in MySQL on reduced tables

Tags: mysql, rdbms, node-mysql

My 3 tables:

**posts**

[image]

**tags:**

[image]

**post2tags:**

[image]

So in the `posts` table I did not reference anything related to `tags`. And in the `tags` table, no reference for `posts`. I created a new table, `posts2tags` and referenced the `posts` for `tags` there.

**Question:** Is this the proper way to do it? Do I need to have any reference for `posts` in `tags` table and vice versa?

What I want to achieve is to return everything from the `posts` table and all `tag` `names` where the `post` is referenced for `tags` (in `posts2tags` table) and have all the tag `names` in an `array/single row` in the result. Like this:

[image]

**Tried :**

```
SELECT p.idPost, p.title, t.name from posts as p, tags as t, post2tags
 WHERE t.idTags=post2tags.idTags
```

**Result:**

[image]

I'm learning to join multiple tables and reduce the table to only required information from it. So looking for advice on that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its the right way to store [`ManyToMany`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) relation the junction table (post2tags) will hold the references for posts and tags to relate them. To get the expected results you can use left join to get all posts whether they have tags or not

```
select p.idPost, p.title, t.name
from posts as p
left join post2tags pt on (p.idPost = pt.idPost)
left join tags t  on (t.idTags = pt.idTags)
order by p.idPost
```

this will return you all the post with their related tags, Each will be returned multiple times as no. of assigned tags like

```
idPost  title  name
-------------------
 1      test   tag1
 1      test   tag2
 2      test   tag1
 2      test   tag2
 3      test   null
```

then in application code you can display these results as per you desired format by doing some if/else logic to show post once only and display its tags.

Another hacky way would be use of [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function which returns comma separated list of values per group like below but it has some limitation of character length.

```
select p.idPost, p.title, group_concat(t.name) as `name`
from posts as p
left join post2tags pt on (p.idPost = pt.idPost)
left join tags t  on (t.idTags = pt.idTags)
group by p.idPost
order by p.idPost
```

this will give you results as per your desired view

```
idPost  title  name
-------------------
 1      test   tag1,tag2
 2      test   tag1,tag2
 3      test   null
```